# Problems with full_join in R. no applicable method to "character"

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I am new to R world I am struggling with full_join function. I am pretty sure the problem is easy. I got it working on other situations I assume they were the same as the present one. Anyhow, probably someone can help me. Let's go:

I have several datasets within a big list:

```
NDVI2003 <- ls(pattern = "x2003_meanNDVI_m.*$") 
PixelQa2003 <- ls(pattern = "x2003_meanPixelQa_m.*$") 
full_list <- do.call(c, list(NDVI2003,PixelQa2003))
```

The first 2 functions are just grabbing some files from a folder. This files look like:

```
> str(x2003_meanNDVI_m1)
'data.frame':   354 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ date       : chr  "2001-12-03" "2001-12-10" "2001-12-19" "2001-12-26" ...
 $ 2003_NDVI_1: num  0.441 0.518 0.322 0.311 0.499 0.319 0.163 0.134 0.452 0.536 ...
 $ 2003_NDVI_2: num  0.377 0.446 0.075 0.1 0.006 0.279 0.368 0.135 0.423 0.522 ...
 $ 2003_NDVI_3: num  0.332 0.397 0.07 0.093 0.006 0.236 0.469 0.127 0.411 0.535 ...
 $ 2003_NDVI_4: num  0.653 0.621 0.536 0.064 0.652 0.576 0.52 0.158 0.666 0.663 ...
```

The 3rd function is simply getting together all these files:

```
    > head(full_list,20)
 [1] "x2003_meanNDVI_m1"    "x2003_meanNDVI_m2"    "x2003_meanNDVI_m3"    "x2003_meanNDVI_m4"    "x2003_meanNDVI_m5"   
 [6] "x2003_meanNDVI_m6"    "x2003_meanPixelQa_m1" "x2003_meanPixelQa_m2" "x2003_meanPixelQa_m3" "x2003_meanPixelQa_m4"
[11] "x2003_meanPixelQa_m5" "x2003_meanPixelQa_m6"
```

So far, very simple. Now it comes to the problem... I want to join all these files by the column 'date'. This very same procedure is working on other scripts I built:

```
data2003 <- reduce(full_list, full_join, by="date")
```

But I keep getting an error:

```
> data2003 <- reduce(full_list, full_join, by="date")
Error in UseMethod("full_join") : 
  no applicable method for 'full_join' applied to an object of class "character"
```

So far, what I have tried:

- Changing the column type from character, to date, to number... **Nothing**.
- Altering the order of dplyr and plyr packages when opening R.
- Changing variable names and so on.
- `full_lst <- list(NDVI2003,PixelQa2003)` instead of     `full_list <- do.call(c, list(NDVI2003,PixelQa2003))`
- -Adding `full_list <- mget(full_list)`
- Google for hours lookin for an answer...

Any help will be really welcome.

Comment: I don't think you need to convert your list into a vector. Try `reduce(list(NDVI2003,PixelQa2003), full_join, by="date")`

Comment: Thanks Dave! I keep having the very same error...

Comment: You have a character vector of names of dataframes. You need to put the actual dataframes themselves in a list, then you can use `reduce` and `full_join`. Try `full_list <- mget(full_list)`

Comment: Hi Brian! I tried that. Got `Error in mget(full_list) : invalid first argument`

Comment: It looks like `mget()` takes character vectors as the first argument.  Try `mget(unlist(full_list))`.

Comment: That was it! I was creating kind of a list of 2 lists, instead of a list of dataframes. With unlist you "unnest" the whole thing. Thank you very much, you were all right!

Comment: Anyone has any idea to simplify my code? `full_list <- list(NDVI2003,PixelQa2003) 
full_list <- mget(unlist(full_list)) ` So "merging" these 2 functions into a single one.